# ion-slides support landscape orientation ionic application

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, ion-slides

I want to show slide images in portrait and landscape orientation.

**Problem : When i rotate image image not set in full screen width**

Here is my code

```
<ion-slides color = "light" #mySlider  (ionSlideAutoplayStop)="autoPlay(mySlider)" (ionSlidesDidLoad)="slidesDidLoad(mySlider)" *ngIf="slideData && slideData.length"  autoplay="50" loop="true" speed="500" class="slides" [options]="slideOpts">
    <ion-slide (resized)="mySlider.update()">
      <div class="bg"></div>
    </ion-slide>
    <ion-slide (resized)="mySlider.update()">
      <div class="bg1"></div>
    </ion-slide>
    <ion-slide (resized)="mySlider.update()">
      <div class="bg2"></div>
    </ion-slide>
```

I have added CSS like this on each slide

```
 ion-slides {
      margin-top: 0px;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      flex: 1;
    }

    ion-slide {
      background-color: black;
    }
    .bg-style {
    background: #000000;
  }
  .bg {
  background-image: url(/assets/slide-1.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.bg1 {
background-image: url(/assets/slide-3.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**page.css**

```
ion-slides{
    ion-slide {
      height: 200px;
      width: 100% !important;

      img{
        height: 200px;
        width: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
    }
  }
}
```